# convert json to C# class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to convert the following to a C# class, can anyone help please? I have tried many different mutations but none can actually map the `Params` to the class.

```json
{
    "method": "update",
    "params": [
        true,
        {
            "y": [
                [
                    "3",
                    "5"
                ],
                [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]               
            ],
            "x": [
                [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ],
                [
                    "2",
                    "1"
                ]
            ],
            "id": 1111,
            "update": 164227,
            "current": 164227
        },
        "TESTING"
    ],
    "id": null
}
```

The following is what I could generate so far, but unfortunately, it can't map the `Params` to the class, I want to get the values of `X` and `Y` in a list:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public List<ParamTest> Params { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public object Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParamClass
{
    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public string[][] X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public string[][] Y { get; set; }
}

public struct ParamTest
{
    public bool Bool;
    public List<ParamClass> ParamClass;
    public string String;

    public static implicit operator ParamTest(bool Bool) => new ParamTest { Bool = Bool };
    public static implicit operator ParamTest(List<ParamClass> ParamClass) => new ParamTest { ParamClass = ParamClass };
    public static implicit operator ParamTest(string String) => new ParamTest { String = String };
}
```

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/json-to-csharp

Comment: @Steve I tried all kind of those online tools., none working! quicktype. json2csharp, and 10 more..

Comment: Have you tryied to write custom converter for the property

Comment: @spzvtbg, I used those converters that are generated by online tools, but no idea how to write one, are you able to come up with an example?

Comment: You can use the Special Paste feature of Visual Studio (Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes to generate the corresponding classes.

Comment: Hmm, did QuickType really fail to provide working classes for it? It looked to me like it was writing a boatload of reasonable custom deser when I slung a mixed array into it.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNu3v.jpg

Comment: @Markus really? Even with that nasty params array in there? PJAC is quite basic compated to the other json-to-somelang services you can discover (and the OP claims have been tried)..

Comment: (Re the "QuickType didn't work" claim, I have to admit I didn't test it (I'm on a cellphone) when I made that screenshot above, but did you deser like it says to in the comments at the top of the generated code? I.e. using their generated `FromJson` helper that registers the generated custom converters etc or did you use it in a basic `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeQTClass>(str)` way without the custom converter..)

Comment: @CaiusJard Well it might generate something weired like an object array or something but by just selecting that part it is possible to create a sub class for that. And names like "param" are no problem as long as they are prefixed with "@" ;-)

Comment: @EmilyWong Why did you use set `[JsonProperty("x")]` on property `Y`?

Answer (score 1):

try this. It was tested in Visual Studio and working properly

```
    var po = JObject.Parse(json); 

    Data data = new Data { Id = (string)po["id"], Method = (string)po["method"] 

    var pars = new ParamObject { };

    foreach (var element in (JArray)po["params"])
    {
        var type = element.GetType().Name;
        if (element.GetType().Name == "JValue")
        {
            if ((string)element == "TESTING")
                pars.Testing = (string)element;
            else pars.IsTrue = (bool)element;
        }
        else if (element.GetType().Name == "JObject")
        {
            pars.XYElement = element.ToObject<XYElement>();
        }
    }
    data.Pars = pars;
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public ParamObject Pars { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class ParamObject
{
    [JsonProperty("XYElement")]
    public XYElement XYElement { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsTrue")]
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TESTING")]
    public string Testing { get; set; }
}
public partial class XYElement
{
    [JsonProperty("y")]
    public List<List<long>> Y { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("x")]
    public List<List<long>> X { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("update")]
    public long Update { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("current")]
    public long Current { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the unstructured data structure, you must use `Object` for deserialization.

Use following classes

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public List<Object> Params { get; set; }
    public int? ID { get; set; }
}
public class Params
{
   public string[][] X { get; set; }
   public string[][] Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then now use

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(json);
var paramsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Params>(data.Params[1].ToString());
```